# What's the purpose of a leading "::" in a C++ method call

Tags: c++, boost, scope-resolution-operator

I've been using the Boost libraries, and in Boost.Exception, I've noticed code like the following:

```
#define BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(x) ::boost::throw_exception(x)
```

Just out of curiosity: what is the purpose of the leading `::` before `boost::throw_exception(x)`?

Answer (score 51):

To refer to the root namespace.  This is often useful if your class or you namespace uses a name which also exists in the root, but at some point you wish to refer to the root version.

For example, if I have overloaded `new` in my class, but wish at some point to refer to the default (root) `new`, then I would use `::new` to refer to root new.

Answer (score 37):

To indicate this is a top level name space.

It is very similar (but not identical) to how a directory name works.  Without the leading double-colon, C++ will first check if there is a namespace of that name within the current 'active' namespace.  If there isn't then it will check for a namespace of the name at the top level.

With the leading double-colon, C++ will skip the first check and only look for a top-level namespace.