# The namespace starts with :: in C++

Tags: c++, namespaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the purpose of a leading “::” in a C++ method call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053398/whats-the-purpose-of-a-leading-in-a-c-method-call)

[This gtest](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md) has the example code.

```
::testing::AssertionResult IsEven(int n) {
  if ((n % 2) == 0)
    return ::testing::AssertionSuccess();
  else
    return ::testing::AssertionFailure() << n << " is odd";
}
```

How does it work? If the namespace is testing, isn't it testing::AssertionResult is the  right usage?

Comment: This ensures that `testing` is not a namespace within another namespace. I think using `::testing` ensures you're using the namespace `testing` at the top level (but don't take my advice, I'm a C++ noob).

Comment: The unary scope operator is used here to avoid a namespace conflict that occurs if the namespace in scope contains a nested namespace named "testing". For example:  "namespace foo { namespace testing {} class FooTest : public testing::Test {}; }"  does not invoke GTest's testing namespace. Instead, it's using foo.testing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The :: prefix refers to the global namespace, so this is like an absolute versus relative path specification.

Comment: I strongly advise the use of ::std for C++ standard library members. Don't just use plain "std" in case someone has a namespace called "std" in scope (happened to me!)

Comment: @Yttrill: Time to invest in a baseball bat and a marker pen. Write "Dont make your own std" on the bad and pay a surprise visit.